# How to run IO inside ScottyM

Tags: haskell, scotty

I'm using `Scotty` to write a small web apps.
I need to run `IO` inside the `ScottyM` type.

There are several difficulties:

First I can't automatically derive type synonyms from `MonadIO` in order to run `liftIO`:

```
type ScottyM = ScottyT Text IO
```

Second, I don't know how to derive ScottyT from `MonadIO`:

```
newtype ScottyT e m a

Constructors
ScottyT  

    runS :: State (ScottyState e m) a
```

What are my options?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `I can't automatically derive type synonyms`? The `ScottyM` alias already exists, you don't need to re-declare it. Same for the second question: what do you mean by "derive"? As for "How to run IO inside ScottyM?", the answer is easy: use `liftIO`

Comment: @Sir4ur0n is right : use liftIO.

Comment: Can't use liftIO, ScottyM is not an instance of MonadIO

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary for you to run your IO inside `ScottyM` instead of before you start `scotty`?

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Web.Scotty

import Data.Monoid (mconcat)

main = do
    print "Hello world!" -- Or your IO action of choice
    scotty 3000 $
        get "/:word" $ do
            beam <- param "word"
        html $ mconcat ["<h1>Scotty, ", beam, " me up!</h1>"]
```

Another option is to abuse `notFound` and `next` to run IO in `ActionM`, which is more straightforward:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Web.Scotty

import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)
import Data.Monoid (mconcat)

main = scotty 3000 $ do
    notFound $ do
        lift $ print "Hello world!" -- Or some other IO action
        next
    get "/:word" $ do
        beam <- param "word"
        html $ mconcat ["<h1>Scotty, ", beam, " me up!</h1>"]
```